# Escape single quotes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to build a SharePoint 2010 `listdata.svc` query that resembles:

```
http://server/FooList/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/FooList?$select=Title,Id,OwnerId,Status&$filter=(OwnerId eq 1234 and Status eq 'Ready')
```

Single quotes don't work:

```
$url = $url + '&$filter=(OwnerId eq 1234 and Status eq 'Ready')'
```

Nor does escaping them with back-ticks:

```
$url = $url + '&$filter=(OwnerId eq 1234 and Status eq `'Ready`')'
```

If I use double quotes, `$filter` is replaced with a zero-length string (it's not a variable in the script):

```
$url = $url + "&$filter=(OwnerId eq 1234 and Status eq 'Ready')"
```

What's the correct way to escape single quotes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to double the quotes when using single-quoted string literals:

```
'&$filter=(OwnerId eq 1234 and Status eq ''Ready'')'
                                         ^^     ^^
```

Demo:

```
PS > '&$filter=(OwnerId eq 1234 and Status eq ''Ready'')'
&$filter=(OwnerId eq 1234 and Status eq 'Ready')
PS >
```

Using backticks only works with double-quoted string literals (since they process escape sequences), but then you also need to escape all other special characters (e.g. the `$` in variable names):

```
PS > "&`$filter=(OwnerId eq 1234 and Status eq `"Ready`")"
&$filter=(OwnerId eq 1234 and Status eq "Ready")
PS >
```

But in a single-quoted string literal, the `` ` `` is treated as a literal backtick.